# Android Settings Bar below Tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.4-kitkat

I have just started working on a new tabbed App.
For some reason, I can't seem to be able to get rid for a settings action item with its own bar that goes below my tab bar.

Anyone know what this is all about?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    ActionBar.Tab mapTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("TEST1");
    ActionBar.Tab infoTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("TEST2");
    ActionBar.Tab settingsTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("TEST3");

    mapTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragment));
    infoTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragment));
    settingsTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragment));

    actionBar.addTab(mapTab, 0, false);
    actionBar.addTab(infoTab, 1, false);
    actionBar.addTab(settingsTab, 2, false);
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nfcproducttracing"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.nfcproducttracing.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you are adding that action item in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` of your activity. If you do not want that action item, remove it.